# Получить результат SQL запроса с помощью вывода другого

Tags: sql, sqlite, perl

Добрый день. Как получить результат SQL запроса базируясь на данных из другого.

```
    my $COUNTER =0;
while ($COUNTER<=900){
my $sql = "SELECT f1 FROM TND where ID='$COUNTER'";
my $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute();
  my $A=$sth->fetchrow_arrayref();
my $sql1 = "select ID,f1,sum(f2) from TND where f1='@$A'";
my $sth1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
my $B;
my @B;
while(@B=$sth1->fetchrow_arrayref()){
print "@B";
  };
$COUNTER++;
}
```

Скрипт завершается ничего мне не отдав.

Comment: Интересно, что за ID вы получаете во втором запросе. вы же в той строке получаете сумму f2 всех записей с f1=$A, а следовательно в поле ID будет из первой попавшийся записи по такому условию (не обязательно по порядку, а как повезет). А вообще ваш запрос стоило бы переписать как `select a.f1, sum(a.f2) from TND a, TND b where a.f1=b.f1 and b.id between 0 and 900 group by a.f1`

Answer (score 0):

> Как получить результат SQL запроса базируясь на данных из другого.

Если результат первого запроса больше ни для чего не нужен (а он вроде как не нужен) - то составить один запрос, который сразу получает необходимые данные.